# Difficulty in creating tabs in angular7

Tags: angular7

In my application I want to create a tabs inside the the div which is used to display the grid using datatables. Based on the tab click i want to display the grids respectively

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to use the [Angular Material tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview).

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="tab1">
      <div>
       ......
      </div>
  <mat-tab label="tab2">
   <div>
    .....
   </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-group>
```